# borker advertise internal domain in k8s cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I install the `bitnami/kafka` cluster with helm.

I want to make producers and consumers not in k8s cluster, This is my helm install config yaml file.

```yaml
replicaCount: 3

service:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 192.168.99.110
  nodePorts:
    client: 25100
    external: 25101

externalAccess:
  enabled: true
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
    port: 9094
    nodePorts:
    - 25100
    - 25101
    loadBalancerIPs:
    - 192.168.99.120
    - 192.168.99.121
```

I expected each broker will advertise own address, but they are giving kubernetes internal domain address like `kf-kafka-1.kf-kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092`

please help me what I miiss

Comment: Look at [this](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/kafka/values.yaml#L617-L713) section, You need to set `externalAccess.enabled: true` and `externalAccess.service` based on your need.

Comment: @SaikatChakrabortty thanks, i think I already set all properties to access from external. I want to set My Consumer like this `new KafkaConsumer("192.168.99.120:25100,192.168.99.121:25101`
* i changed my properties

Answer (score 0):

I treid to connect port on `externalAccess.service.nodePorts`

but should use just `{externalAccess.service.loadBalancerIPs[n]}:9004`

thanks.